# Slack installation/boot error: ssh: Could not resolve hostname slack-master Name or Service not known

Tags: linux, ssh, installation, slack, linux-mint

I cannot open my downloaded slack application. Using linux mint. Receiving error message when typing `slack` into the terminal

I am trying to install slack on my linux mint machine (which is really just ubuntu). I have tried installing with `sudo apt-get install slack` as well as using the snapd package manager. Both seem to install slack just fine. But when I type slack into my applications list, it does not appear. Furthermore, when I type slack from the terminal (to open slack) I get the following error message (I have removed some details of the error message for safety and security reasons):

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname slack-master: Name or service not known

rsync: did not see server greeting

rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5)  ............

FATAL[slack-getroles]: 'rsync --links --times -e ssh slack-master::
really_long_pathname_which_I_have_excluded

FATAL[slack]: pathname_which_I_have_excluded
```

You could reasonably call me a linux noob. I have only been using Ubuntu and Mint for about 4 years. So I could just be missing something quite telling. For example, the website I was using to install slack told me to resolve dependencies. I followed their instructions but to be honest I dont know what dependencies are (are they like external libraries or crates that we need to import/keep updated? --I will give it a google after I post this). Anyways, here is the quick little guide I used (note that mint is the same as ubuntu under the hood, its kinda like the difference between Windows10S and Windows10)

https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/install-slack-on-linux/

All help would be greatly appreciated, I am willing to post more information if necessary.

Comment: You apparently need to use the package provided by the slack developers.   you can download it directly from https://slack.com/downloads/linux